# PNG image sequence playing problem

Tags: iphone, image, png, sequence

Ok, I have a button that, when pressed, should animate/play a png image sequence.

My problem is -

- I press the button (button A) and the image sequence plays - which is good!
- but then I press (button A) again and nothing happens. - bad.
- but then... if I press (button A) a third time - the image sequence plays.

**So basically, the image sequence only plays every second time I press the button**?...I can't think what could be causing that?

Another scenario which might give you clues to the problem -

- I press the button (button A) and everything works fine
- I press a different button (**button B**) and it does its different thing
- Then I press (button A) again and everything works fine.

**So it seems, the image sequence only plays if something else happens in between (button A) presses?**

Any ideas?

Here is the code... The views "viewDidLoad" has [self loadAnimX01];

```
    - (void) loadAnimX01 {

    x01 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35.0f, 112.0f,70.0f, 115.0f)];
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) 
        [array addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pipe01_%02d.png",i]]];
    x01.animationImages = array;
    x01.animationDuration = 0.7;
    x01.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [self.view addSubview:x01];
    [x01 release];
}

- (IBAction)pX01 {
    [x01 startAnimating];
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i figured out a solution. But I still cant make sense of it!?

- I have to check to see if the sequence is playing
- Then stop the sequence
- Then play it.

This makes the the image sequence play every time I press the button

If anyone could tell my why my I have to do this... please let me know

Here is my solution

```
- (IBAction)pX01{
if ([x01 isAnimating]) { 
    [x01 stopAnimating];
}
[x01 startAnimating];
```

}

Thanks!

Comment: You should mark this question as correct. It makes it easier for others having the same problem to find it.